# Is there an issue with the edit history or are these two just trolling?

Tags: bug, revision-history

It's this question and answer: [Trouble with logic in this conditional statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37302948/trouble-with-logic-in-this-conditional-statement)

The TL;DR is that supposedly there was a typo in the code that was edited out, however you look at the history and there is no evidence to support the fact the typo was ever there, yet the OP said his problem is fixed.

Is this just an issue with the history not showing correctly?

Comment: He's just saying that his snippet was not his real code.  So he added the note and posted his real code.  Wrong variable name.  This is useless, how it got 8 helpful votes is beyond me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that the OP realized the mistake they made during the grace period and fixed it.

That would explain why it never showed up in the revision history. I suspect that the person who answered started working on the problem before the edit was made and thus was able to find the error.

With my newly-found VTC powers, I voted to close it as a typo.

Comment: Ah grace period, of course. That's mildly annoying in this instance, thankfully it's edge case.

Comment: The accepted answer was posted less than 3 minutes after the question, so yeah, well within the grace period. OP made a ninja edit and [hoped nobody would notice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37302948/trouble-with-logic-in-this-conditional-statement#comment62128353_37302948).

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Yeah, I started writing this question probably the moment that comment was posted :)